# Windows 10 constantly ducking audio

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have the standard communication audio ducking set to "do nothing".  No matter what, in every program I use, Windows ducks the audio.

The program creating the sound is shown pushing full volume in the mixer, but everywhere else (speakers, and Rainmeter, to capture for my equalizer visual) show lower.  I'm not sure how much lower, but it's a large enough margin that I noticed.

Yes, I've rebooted countless times.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what ducks have to do with an audio problem

Comment: Ducking is when the program lowers volume when another audio signal is noticed. Announcers use them all the time when they talk over a signal.

Comment: So you have or have not been to the Communications tab of the Sound dialog and set it to "Do nothing"? It's not very clear in your question as you used the term "ducking" instead of what Windows calls it.